# Possibility to define line endings in sphinx-apidoc

Tags: python-sphinx

When running sphinx-apidoc on windows it creates .rst files with windows line endings (CRLF)
Is there a possibility to enforce linux line endings (LF).

The problem is that we are using windows and linux PCs but we want to have consistent line endings. The workaround we are using now is a script that converts all line endings for .rst files to LF. But as someone once said: There must be a better way!

If there is no possibility to do this I would open a feature request.

Note: sphinx-apidoc 3.1.2

Comment: [sphinx-apidoc](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html) doesn't provide any argument for this. The templates it uses for generating have `LF` also on Windows. The source code [isn't especially complicated](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/3.x/sphinx/ext/apidoc.py) if you want to adapt it. On a general note I think this feature-request would mostly clutter the documentation without substantial gain because of to the ease in converting the EOL characters after `.rst` generation.

Comment: We had the same problem with isort but since the 5.0 release it uses LF everywhere.